# Is there a way to ensure a type is Serializable at compile time

Tags: scala, shapeless

I work with Spark often, and it would save me a lot of time if the compiler could ensure that a type is serializable.

Perhaps with a type class?

```
def foo[T: IsSerializable](t: T) = {
  // do stuff requiring T to be serializable
}
```

It's not enough to constrain T <: Serializable. It could still fail at runtime. Unit tests are a good substitute, but you can still forget them, especially when working with big teams.

I think this is probably impossible to do at compile time without the types being sealed.

Comment: Side question: Is T <: Serializable only a compile time guarantee?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Yes, it is a constraint checked at compile time.

Comment: But, what's the point of having a powerful type system if it does not provide runtime guarantees?

Comment: This is a Java problem, not a Scala type system problem. T <: Serializable does guarantee that you can never call a function with a type that could never be serialized in any context. The actual problem is that extending Serializable doesn't guarantee that an instance can be serialized by Java. You can always extend a class marked as serializable and add members that aren't serializable, breaking it at runtime.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not in the way that you're hoping. Your type class `IsSerializable` could provide a mechanism to convert your `T` to a value of a type which *is* guaranteed to be `Serializable` and back again,

```
trait IsSerializable[T] {
  def toSerializable(t: T): String
  def fromSerializable(s: String): Option[T]
}
```

But, of course, this is just an alternative type class based serialization mechanism in it's own right, making the use of JVM serialization redundant.

Your best course of action would be to lobby Spark to support type class based serialization directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you're right, this is not what I was hoping for :) If spark moved away from Java serialization, how would it serialize closures? Solving the serialization of data objects with type classes is simple enough, but the computation logic doesn't seem possible. It's a shame because most Spark applications are riddled with lazies and other workarounds to serialization gotchas.